# Recurrence and Inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

What is the standard (if it exists) way to solve a recurrence $$a_n\leq \alpha a_{n-1}+\beta a_{n-2}?$$

We can suppose $\alpha, \beta>0$ are positive and real.

Comment: What sort of solution are you looking for? There won't exist real numbers $\{b_n\}$ so that a sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfies this inequality iff $a_n\leq b_n$ for all $n$.

More generally, what is the source of this question? If we know where this came from we will be better able to give you an answer that will be useful.

Comment: It's not coming from anywhere really, just something I was thinking about. I would think that one might be able to show $a_n=\mathcal{O} ((\beta/\alpha)^n)$.

Comment: we can even assume $x_n>0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Idea: think about characteristic equation, i.e. $x^2\leq\alpha x-\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

For me the standard way is applied when we are given *non-negative* $a_0$ and $a_1$. Then for each $n$ we have $a_n\le b_n$, where $b_0=a_0$, $b_1=a_1$, and $b_n=\alpha b_{n-1}+\beta b_{n-2}$ for each $n\ge 2$, and this bound is tight. The recurrence for $b_n$ is order two homogeneous linear recurrence with constant coefficients, which can be solved via the [standard way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).